Trying to filter "managers" field to only show managers in the currently logged in user's department
I have three models:

The base User model that Django provides
UserProfile, a model that has 2 fields:
a foreignkey field with the user table
a department field that's a choicefield with a dropdown, every user has 1 department
A Data model that contains a Manager field, a many-to-many with the user model

Models:
class Data(models.Model):
    """Model representing each event's data."""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 2000)
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="event_co_manager_user", 
                                      blank=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """Model representing the user profile"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    DEPARTMENT_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Dep1'),
        (1, 'Dep2'),
        (2, 'Dep3'),
    )

    department = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=DEPARTMENT_CHOICES, 
                                 null=True)

I am trying to filter the manager field on the backend to only show managers that share the same department, since we don't want people to be able to add other departments as managers in their events.
This is the function that I'm trying to overwrite in my admin.py (using Django 5.0):
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "managers":
        kwargs["queryset"] = Data.objects.filter(
            managers.userprofile.department == request.user.userprofile.department
        )

    return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

I keep getting errors about the managers field not having an attribute of userprofile.

Please share (relevant parts of) your models.

Updated with models

But this is a ModelAdmin for Data or User or UserProfile?

Could you please share the full error message?

These are the models for UserProfile and Data, the User model is the prebuilt one for django

Department is not a ForeignKey?

When you want to construct a query that will span relationships, such as when you want to filter on a ForeignKey attribute, you need to use dunder instead of period to access those relationships.
Replace:
Data.objects.filter(managers.userprofile.department ==

with:
Data.objects.filter(managers__userprofile__department ==


Got to to work, just needed to modify the query a bit to pull the actual information:

You can set the queryset with:
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'managers':
        kwargs['queryset'] = Data.objects.filter(
            managers__userprofile__department=request.user.userprofile.department
        )

    return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
but this will make an extra query to get the .userprofile of the request.user. Additionally using choices=… [Django-doc] for something that can "grow" is often not a good idea.
Typically one uses an extra model, like:
class Data(models.Model):
    "Model representing each event's data."
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='event_co_manager_user', blank=True
    )


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    'Model representing the user profile'
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    department = models.ForeignKey(
        Department,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='userprofiles',
        null=True,
    )
Then it thus looks like:
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'managers':
        kwargs['queryset'] = Data.objects.filter(
            managers__userprofile__department__userprofile__user=request.user
        )

    return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
